# VSTO MsProject get task duration as string as i see it on the screen

Tags: c#, .net, vsto, office-addins, ms-project

The default display unit of duration is hours. The `task.Duration` cell contains the value in minutes. How to get a value in hours into a variable?
For example.

In display I see    **5h**

in variable `Task.Duration  = 300`

me need

```
string s = Task.Duration;
```

s must be equal to 5

In the d variable, I need to get what I see on the screen, regardless of the value of the duration unit settings.

5*60 is not suitable. `MsProject` duration rounds up to integers. And the value after * may not match what is on the screen.

thanks

Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1):

The [Duration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.task.duration) property of the task object returns the value in minutes; use this to get the most precise answer. Alternatively, use the [GetField](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.task.getfield) method to return the *displayed* value (String). For example:

```
string taskDuration = task.GetField(188743709);
```

See this list of [enumerated field constants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.pjfield).

Also try searching stackoverflow for [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bms-project%5D%20%5Bc%23%5Dgetfield).

Comment: Tell me please, is it possible to get the value of duration in seconds? without multiplying minutes by 60. Seconds are important to me. But the time is entered in hours. I have to convert to seconds and back. 11.16h *60 = 669.6 msproj rounded 670 * 60 = 40200. 11.17h*60 = 670.2 rouded 670 = 40200. MSproject rounds minutes to integers. I am getting error.  thanks

Comment: Duration is stored in minutes and displayed rounded to hundredths of whatever unit is used (hours, days, etc). Use the *stored value* from the Duration field and not the displayed value that is rounded and then you won't have errors.